# MySQL preventing insert with foreign key

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

How might you prevent INSERTs or UPDATEs in MySQL if one value in another table matches another, but the value itself isn't a key? The answer must be a FOREIGN KEY constraint but I'm not sure exactly how it works with multiple columns as well as non-key fields.

My own situation is this:

Given this table USERDATA with these values:

```
ID | USER_ID | UUID
 1     29       aaa
 2     29       bbb
 3     30       ccc
```

and this table RELATIONS with these values after INSERT, where userdata_uuid refs uuid and receiver_id refs user_id

```
ID | USERDATA_UUID | RECEIVER_ID
1         aaa           29
2         aaa           30
3         bbb           29
4         bbb           30
5         ccc           29
6         ccc           30
```

how can I prevent an insert that depicts a user having a relation to their own userdata? With this data, the desired result after an INSERT on RELATIONS would be:

```
ID | USERDATA_UUID | RECEIVER_ID
1         aaa           30
2         bbb           30
3         ccc           29
```

Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: What columns in relations are non nullable?

Comment: The ones I've posted are all non-nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with triggers.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_relations
BEFORE INSERT ON relations
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.userdata_uuid = IF(EXISTS(
      SELECT * 
        FROM userdata
       WHERE uuid = NEW.userdata_uuid
         AND user_id = NEW.receiver_id), NULL, NEW.userdata_uuid);

CREATE TRIGGER tg_bu_relations
BEFORE UPDATE ON relations
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.userdata_uuid = IF(EXISTS(
      SELECT * 
        FROM userdata
       WHERE uuid = NEW.userdata_uuid
         AND user_id = NEW.receiver_id), NULL, NEW.userdata_uuid);
```

The trick is to violate `NOT NULL` constraint if conditions for your check is met.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd790/1)** demo
*Try to uncomment two last insert and update statements one at a time. Triggers won't let them to succeed.*